# Calculate standard deviation recursively

Tags: c, function, recursion, computer-science

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
double foo(int n, double mean, int n2){
    double square;
    if(n==1){
        return(1);
    }
    if(n!=0){

        return( (sqrt((n-mean)*(n-mean))+foo(n-1,mean,n2))/(sqrt(n2-1))  );
    }


}
int main(){
    int num;
    int n2;
    double mean;
    int i;
    int sum=0;

    printf("Enter the number: ");
    scanf("%d",&num);
    n2=num;
    for(i=1; num>=i; i++){
        sum=sum+i;
    }
    mean=(double)sum/num;
    printf("%lf ",mean);
    foo(num,mean,n2);    
    printf(" %lf ",foo(num,mean,n2));
}
```

I want to calculate standard deviation. The formula is https://i.pinimg.com/originals/b5/7c/a0/b57ca00c2aabd05bcb722295734ba2e6.png

Comment: It looks odd that you calculate `square=pow(n-mean,2);` and the only usage is `sqrt(square)`

Comment: I think your math is wrong but let's start here: In `main` you have a `double mean` but `foo` works with `int mean`.

Comment: right, i should write foo(int n, double mean).

Comment: Why do you want to use recursion? This task is not a task that shall be solved by recursion. Simply do: `sqrt(n*(n+1)/(n-1));` and you are done.

Comment: return( (sqrt((n-mean)*(n-mean))+foo(n-1,mean))/(sqrt(n-1))  );

Comment: My teacher  asked to me do this in this way.

Comment: You could use Welford's algorithm, eg https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithms_for_calculating_variance

Comment: BTW: you say you want to calculate standard deviation and you want to use the formula  `sqrt( (6+5+4+3+2+1)/(5) )`. I don't think that's it's done like that.

Comment: Perhaps your teacher meant to use a recursive function to calculate the sum of the squares of the differences between the mean and the values. Although that is an abuse of recursion (it is inefficient and not well served by recursion), it is of appropriate difficulty for a student learning recursion. In contrast, writing a function that returns the fully computed standard deviation by calling itself recursively is somewhat difficult and not generally suitable for a student just learning about recursion.

Comment: https://i.pinimg.com/originals/b5/7c/a0/b57ca00c2aabd05bcb722295734ba2e6.png

This is the formula that I tried write

Comment: I am not allowed to use loop.

Comment: You tried too hard to use recursion. __Only__ use it for the repeating part of the formula, in this case: Σ(xᵢ-x̅)²

Comment: I can't only use it for the repeating part.

Comment: @anonim: It is very unlikely your teacher intended you to write a function that directly returns the standard deviation and calls itself to do so. If you believe that is the case, then please edit your question to include the exact text of the assignment.

Comment: @anonim Then at least keep the non-repeating part in the final iteration; taking the square root in __every__ iteration is just plain wrong.

Comment: how to keep the non-repeating part in the last iteration

Answer (score 1):

This assignment is kind of strange as this is not a problem that should be solved using recursion. Though, it will be strange, it is doable.

For n=2 you want

```
F1: SD(2) = sqrt(((2-mean)^2 + (1-mean)^2)/(2-1))
```

this can be written as:

```
F2: (2-1) * SD(2)^2 = (2-mean)^2 + (1-mean)^2
```

For n=3 you want

```
F3: SD(3) = sqrt(((3-mean)^2 + (2-mean)^2 + (1-mean)^2)/(3-1))
```

Now insert the `(2-mean)^2 + (1-mean)^2` from F2 above and you get:

```
F4: SD(3) = sqrt(((3-mean)^2 + (2-1) * SD(2)^2)/(3-1))
                                       ^^^^^
                                 Here is the recursion
```

In more general term the formula would be:

```
SD(n) = sqrt(((n - mean)^2 + (n-1-1) * (SD(n-1))^2)/(n-1))
```

So the recursive call would be something like:

```
double foo(int n, double mean)
{
    if (n == 2) return sqrt(pow(2-mean, 2) + pow(1-mean, 2));
    return sqrt((pow(n-mean, 2) + (n-2)*pow(foo(n-1, mean), 2))/(n-1));
                                           // ^^^
                                           // recursive call
}
```

Not nice but doable.

So a full program that has both the recursive-method and the better loop-method could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

// Recursive method
double foo(int n, double mean)
{
    if (n == 2) return sqrt(pow(2-mean, 2) + pow(1-mean, 2));
    return sqrt((pow(n-mean, 2) + (n-2)*pow(foo(n-1, mean), 2))/(n-1));
                                           // ^^^
                                           // recursive call
}

// Loop method
double bar(int n, double mean)
{
    double x = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <=n; ++i)
    {
        x = x + pow(i-mean, 2);
    }
    x = x / (n - 1);
    return sqrt(x);
}


int main() {
    int n = 6;
    double mean = (n + 1)/2.0;
    printf("Recursive: %.20f\n", foo(n, mean));
    printf("Loop:      %.20f\n", bar(n, mean));
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Recursive: 1.87082869338697066475
Loop:      1.87082869338697066475
```

Comment: pow(foo(n-1, mean)) - Shouldn't another multiplier be needed

Comment: @anonim yes, I just fixed it. Was missing a `, 2`

Comment: one bracket seems too much or is it missing?

Comment: @anonim Should be ok now

Comment: @anonim Added a complete program that you can copy

Comment: thanks! if I want to calculate the standard deviation some number in array recursively, is still return sqrt((pow(n-mean, 2) + (n-2)*pow(foo(n-1, mean), 2))/(n-1));?

Comment: @anonim I'm not sure what you are asking. Can you explain it further

Answer (score 0):

First of all the mean can be found without using a for loop:

> mean = (num+1)/2

Now coming back to the recursion problem. What you are doing is square rooting and dividing in each recursive step, but you only have to do it once. Usually iterative approach is better, but here is a working solution for the recursive approach:

```
double foo1(int n, double mean){
    double square = pow(n-mean,2);
    if(n==1){
        return square;
    }else{
        return square + foo1(n-1,mean);
    }
}

double foo(int n, double mean){
    return sqrt(foo1(n,mean)/(n-1));
}
```

Here you have two function, one which recursively calculates the sum of squares (foo1), and second which divides the sum by n-1 and returns its root;

EDIT: I think iterative approach is much simpler to implement, plus it can be done with one function

```
double foo(int n, double mean){
    double squareSum = 0;
    int i;
    for(i = 1; i<=n; i++){
        squareSum += pow(i-mean, 2);
    }
    return sqrt(squareSum/(n-1));
}
```

Comment: I am allowed write one function to calculate the formula

Comment: @anonim I have added the solution with one function to the original answer

Answer (score 0):

As you pointed out in the comments, you are only allowed to use one (recursive) function to calculate the standard deviation.

Since part of the formula (most notably, taking the square root) is non-repeating, I recommend using tail recursion with an accumulator.

```
double foo(int i, int n, double mean, double acc)
{
    return i > 0
        ? foo(i - 1, n, mean, acc + pow(i-mean, 2))
        : sqrt(acc / (n-1));
}
```

Call it as:

```
double stddev = foo(num, num, mean, 0.0);
```

Result:

```
1.870829
```